# Why concat a null with text is null?

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, concatenation

Why is the result of concatenating a `null` with a string `null` in sql? How does it work internally?

If you concatenate a column which an empty value with some text, something like next:

```
select '' || 'a'
```

The output would be:

> Output = 'a'

But, in the case you concatenates a null value with a text, the result is `null`

```
select null || 'a'
```

The output would be:

> Output = NULL

So,

- Why am I not getting the same result or getting an error?
- Definitively, how does it work internally?

Comment: An empty string `''` is not null.

Comment: . . . in postgresql

Comment: Because this is how the SQL standard defined it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`null` is not an empty string - it's not even a value. It's a lack thereof. You could think of `null` as an "unknown", missing value. So the result of concatinating an unknown value with `'a'` would be unknown - i.e., `null`.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to concatenate null values in Postgres, you should use **[concat](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html)** function.

According to Postgres documentation:

> **concat(str "any" [, str "any" [, ...] ])**
>
> Concatenate all arguments. NULL arguments are ignored.

```
select concat('Lady', 2, NULL, 'More');
```

Returns:

```
Lady2More
```

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` means **missing value**, it has difference meaning of `''`, which is blank, blank actually has value but is is blank value, you cannot say `NULL` has value, it does not exist. Based on this, any operation with `NULL` will return `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

NULL is a non-value, a nonexistent value. It is not zero. It is not an empty string. A value cannot equal NULL. No two NULL values are equal.

It's a **missing** or **absent** "data" if you have to give it a meaning.

A NULL value is often defined as one that is **unknown** or not applicable, but even these definitions can be open to debate. For instance, a record may not include a customer’s birthdate because the salesperson didn’t ask or because the customer would not provide it, but the customer still knows that date, so it is hardly unknown, nor is it any less applicable.